# Android admob adview force close

Tags: java, android, admob

This is my very first attempt at including ads in my app. I have read the online documentation and read it word for word. Now, the only part I don't get is how to actually request ads and to add it into my app.

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
```

That seems to work so far so good.
Anything else I do will just force close.
For example adding this line:

```
adView.setAdListener(this);
```

I have implemented AdListener to the Activity.

By the way, when I hover over the imported classes:

```
import com.admob.android.ads.AdView;
```

or other similar classes, it says: Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Is that supposed to be correct?

Comment: Can you provide the logs for the crash?   The note is normal.

Comment: 01-10 20:20:11.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2043):     at com.admob.android.ads.AdView.<init>(AdView.java:323)
01-10 20:20:11.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2043):     at com.admob.android.ads.AdView.<init>(AdView.java:308)
01-10 20:20:11.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2043):     at com.admob.android.ads.AdView.<init>(AdView.java:267)
Sorry, never posted a log before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tough to say for sure without seeing your code and your layout, but here are some things you might want to check:

1) The AdMobActivity is declared in your AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
```

2) You request the INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

3) Your attrs.xml file contains the necessary styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
        <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
        <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

4) Your AdView is included in your layout:

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/ad"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
  myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
  myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
/>
```

5) Your AdView is being found properly:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
if (adView == null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AdView not found!");
}
```

Comment: apparently the view is no found. I checked and the xml seems fine. Gonna have to recheck again.

Comment: Ads are now showing up on the emulator but what I still do not get is why it is not working through xml code. I created an AdView through code and now it's working. Bah, I hated xml and for once thought that I could get along and learn xml but this is making it very hard for me.

Comment: Verify that you are calling setContentView with the correct layout and that you are passing the correct ID to findViewById.  It's easy enough to have something like "adview" in one layout and "ad" in another and call findViewById with the wrong one, resulting in null.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with me changing the content view for something else. Every project I remove the R.main.id something like that and create my own through code: LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this), setContentView(ll);

Comment: Yes, that will cause the problem.  You should define as many of the Views as possible in XML.  For anything else, you can define them programatically and then attach them where appropriate (with addView on any ViewGroup).

Comment: This is problem. So the only way to get this current app is to redo the activities with a new xml based layout?