# App force closes on adding admob webview

Tags: android, crash, webview, admob

I have a webview in my app, that's it. I tested it, its working but when i add admob to the code, it starts force closing. I did some commenting to see what's causing it to close and when i remove the Abmob related code from main.xml, it starts working normally.

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="800dp" />

 <com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="a14d--mypub--id--"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can Anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: please add stacktrace from logcat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653763/android-admob-adview-force-close

Comment: http://code.google.com/mobile/afma_ads/docs/android/doubleclick/

Comment: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html

Comment: This is where i am getting error
E/AndroidRuntime(25559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.arv.myapp/com.arv.myapp.myappActivity}: android.view
.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.admob.and
roid.ads.AdView

Answer (score 0):

You need not to take web view for displaying Admob.
Just remove web iew from your xml file then run your application , it will work.else provide that Admob code in separate layout tag.

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/**Prove Your Package name,e.g. com.xyz.abc**"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="a14d--mypub--id--"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Comment: actually i am using webview for something else(that is my app)

Comment: LOGCAT 
E/AndroidRuntime(25559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.arv.mediafire/com.arv.mediafire.MediafireActivity}: android.view
.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.admob.and
roid.ads.AdView