# Why does my Android Activity close when AdMob loads an ad?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

I've been putting AdMob ads in an otherwise working Android app, following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals).  The app has 2 activities.  One of them is only reachable from the first.  I'm currently adding ads to this second activity.  I've tried both creating an `AdView` programmatically in the `onCreate` method and adding appropriate code to the XML layout file for the Activity.  In both cases the activity will exit the second Activity and go to the first as if the back button had been pressed as soon as it recieves an ad (or at least some ad data over the network).  If I change the code so as to not make an add request (even if I add the ad programatically but just don't to call `loadAd`), or if I turn off my netwrok access then I don't see any ads, but my Activity doesn't exit either.  What could be causing this?

I've gone through all the (I believe out of date) steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653763/android-admob-adview-force-close), but that doesn't help.  Just to be clear in case I did something wrong, I have:

- Downloaded the latest Android and AdMob SDKs, at least as of last Friday.
- Set 'target=android-17' in default.properties (which I had to create in the root of the project, since I couldn't fine) and project.properties (which is what I think the project actually uses).
- Set 'android:minSdkVersion="3"' in AndroidManifest.xml.
- Added the library to the project (by placing GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar in a libs directory in the project root).
- Added a `com.google.ads.AdActivity` copied from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) to AndroidManifest.xml.
- Added permission to AndroidManifest.xml, again copied from the same place.
- Copied both code and XML tags (and attributes) from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) and added them to my project (replacing MY_AD_UNIT_ID with my publisher ID), although I also broke out the request in code to make the emulator a test device.
- Added an attrs.xml with ad styles.  I'm fairly certain this is obsolete advice, but I did it anyway.  I used the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653763/android-admob-adview-force-close), although I changed `com.admob.android.ads.AdView` to `com.google.ads`.

The next thing I think you'll want to know if you try to help me is what LogCat says.  Not much:

```
09-02 14:33:34.861: I/Ads(12839): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"com.Package.Name","hl":"en","bas_off":0,"simulator":1,"preqs":0,"slotname":"a150cbaa53d9d3d","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","u_audio":4,"cap":"m,a","cipa":0,"u_sd":1.5,"net":"ed","u_h":533,"oar":0,"session_id":"4834854664722735718","seq_num":"1","app_name":"1.android.com.Package.Name","bas_on":0,"kw":[],"u_w":320,"gnt":3,"adtest":"on","format":"320x50_mb","carrier":"310260","ad_pos":{"visible":0,"width":0,"height":0,"x":0,"y":0},"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
09-02 14:33:35.111: D/dalvikvm(12839): GC freed 8784 objects / 437720 bytes in 64ms
09-02 14:33:37.101: I/Ads(12839): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?msid=com.Package.Name&hl=en&bas_off=0&preqs=0&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&u_audio=4&cap=m%2Ca&cipa=0&u_sd=1.5&net=ed&u_h=533&oar=0&session_id=4834854664722735718&seq_num=1&app_name=1.android.com.Package.Name&bas_on=0&kw&u_w=320&gnt=3&adtest=on&format=320x50_mb&carrier=310260&ptime=0&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14e8f77524dde8&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=interactiveVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=41" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
09-02 14:33:37.111: I/Ads(12839): Request scenario: Online server request.
09-02 14:33:38.061: I/jdwp(12861): received file descriptor 10 from ADB
09-02 14:33:38.091: D/ddm-heap(12861): Got feature list request
```

EDIT:
I don't think it will be very useful, but at the request of suleman khan here is my current XML

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" ads:adUnitId="a150cbaa53d9d3d"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" android:id="@+id/adView" ads:refreshInterval="60" 
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

I"ve tried many variations of this, with no success.

Comment: post your .xml code to be more precise.

Comment: @Edward.D.Baum: I am having a similar problem after integrating the AdMob ads. My MainActivity is a TabActivity and I am showing the ads above the tabs. After selecting a particular tab and navigating a few activities in it and then backpressing instead of coming to the previous activity the app is exiting. I have posted my problem in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877461/how-to-add-or-ignore-adactivity-of-admob-ads-in-android . Could you please let me know if you were able to resolve your issue as I'm still unable to find the solution after trying out a workaround too?

Comment: @IngridCooper Sorry.  I fixed it at some point, but I no longer remember how as it has been months.  I went through my version history and it's possible that the fix was specifying the latest version for `target` in `project.properties`, but I'm not sure about that.

EDIT: And now I just read my question and it appears that I did that before I fixed it.  I really don't know what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in your xml:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="@string/my_publisher_id"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Hope you have added your publisher id.

Place this after your activity in Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

As you said that you have added jar file in libs in your project and hope you have also configured it in your buildpath.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

above code will work, and you can remove these tags also

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8"
```