# How to add or ignore AdActivity of Admob Ads in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a requirement to add or ignore the `AdActivity` of the `Admob` Ads. I am using a `TabActivity` and the activities navigated inside the tabs are maintained in an `ArrayList`. After integrating the ads when I navigate to the 3rd activity in a tab and then back press, instead of coming back to the previous activity (which happened before integrating the ads) I'm coming out of the app. While adding the activities to the `ArrayList` I'm setting the intent flag as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. Could you please tell me how can I overcome coming out of the app on back press in the 3rd `activity` and instead be able to come to the 2nd `activity` and then to the 1st `activity`?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admob/com.example.admob.activity.MainTabActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:87)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.google.ads.doubleclick.DfpAdView.<init>(SourceFile:27)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.example.admob.activity.MainTabActivity.onCreate(MainTabActivity.java:80)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-10 13:19:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: adMob has nothing to do with it... look at the way you are actually calling the activities ..are u calling the finish() also at the time of opening the new activity... FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is actually destroying the activities that are on top of the one u are currently in... so avoid that if you want to move back to activites on back presed

Comment: I debugged the issue and found out that Admob was causing memory leaks. I checked out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946976/why-does-my-android-activity-close-when-admob-loads-an-ad/15912664#15912664 and implemented the same but then I got a Null Pointer Exception. I have edited my question and posted the logs as shown in the Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for it! The problem was with the layout. I changed it accordingly and it worked. The following is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.google.ads.doubleclick.DfpAdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```